# extract CSV columns data to individual Numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy

Extract data from the given SalaryGender CSV file and store the data from each column in a separate NumPy array

SalaryGender.csv sample data

```
Salary,Gender,Age,PhD
140,1,47,1
30,0,65,1
35.1,0,56,0
30,1,23,0
80,0,53,1
```

Comment: The numpy arrays are all easily accessible with `Series.to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

Use: [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

that will create a list where each element has a numpy array of each column:

```
[group.values for i,group in df.groupby(level=0,axis=1)]
```

---

If you aren't looking for a list then use:

```
for i,group in df.groupby(level=0,axis=1):
       print(group.values)
       .....
```

Also you can use [`DataFrame.iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html):

```
for i,col in df.iteritems():
    print(col.to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [199]: txt = """Salary,Gender,Age,PhD 
     ...: 140,1,47,1 
     ...: 30,0,65,1 
     ...: 35.1,0,56,0 
     ...: 30,1,23,0 
     ...: 80,0,53,1"""
```

We can load your sample as a structured array:

```
In [203]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None, delimiter=',', encoding=None, names=True)                                                
In [204]: data                                                                  
Out[204]: 
array([(140. , 1, 47, 1), ( 30. , 0, 65, 1), ( 35.1, 0, 56, 0),
       ( 30. , 1, 23, 0), ( 80. , 0, 53, 1)],
      dtype=[('Salary', '<f8'), ('Gender', '<i8'), ('Age', '<i8'), ('PhD', '<i8')])
```

Each element of the array is a row of the file; field names come from the header line, field dtype is deduced from the data.

Fields can be accessed by name:

```
In [205]: data['Salary']                                                        
Out[205]: array([140. ,  30. ,  35.1,  30. ,  80. ])
In [206]: data['Gender']                                                        
Out[206]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

They can be accessed that way or can be assigned to a variable

```
salary = data['Salary']
```

You can also use `unpack`:

```
In [213]: a,b,c,d = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),  delimiter=',', encoding=Non
     ...: e, skip_header=1, unpack=True)                                        
In [214]: a                                                                     
Out[214]: array([140. ,  30. ,  35.1,  30. ,  80. ])
In [215]: b                                                                     
Out[215]: array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0.])
In [216]: c                                                                     
Out[216]: array([47., 65., 56., 23., 53.])
In [217]: d                                                                     
Out[217]: array([1., 1., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Sometimes it's simpler to load the file one (or selected) column at a time:

```
In [218]: b = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),  delimiter=',', encoding=None, ski
     ...: p_header=1, usecols=[1])                                              
In [219]: b                                                                     
Out[219]: array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```py
SG[SG.columns].values
```

where `SG` is your file name. The code above gives you all columns values in array in a single go.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.